# RegExp Validation (email validation)

Tags: regex, email-validation

I'm using a validation on Field validation that calls a Business Service(BS). In this BS it is performed an email validation with RegExp.

I'm using the following pattern: `^(.+)@([^\(\);:,<>]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10})`

It is expected that the the email termination has between 2 and 10 characters. With 1 character I get the expected error, but the same does not happen with 11 or more characters. I do not get any errors.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: You should show your code. It matters. But you're probably missing a $ at the end of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the "11 or more case", you need to add an end-of-string anchor:

```
^(.+)@([^\(\);:,<>]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10})$
```

Now, something else to consider: http://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/